# multiple instances of named argument in list

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, stored-procedures, oracle10g, ora-06550

I have a problem executing oracle procedures from Visual Studio 2008's Server Explorer,

when i try to execute a procedure all the input parameters are doubled!

it only happend to me in one workstation, i've tried to reinstall oracle products,
but it doesn't helped me...

i get the following error message when i try execute the procedure:

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00703: multiple instances of named argument in list
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

My Data Connection type is "Oracle Database" and the provider is ".NET Framework Data Provider for Oracle".

Best Regards,
Guy Bertental

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service Pack 1 for VS2008 solved the problem...

Answer (score 8):

May be you have added **same** "OracleParameter" ***multiple times***.
Please control your parameter list and **remove repeated** parameter(s) from your code;

Answer (score 6):

use  `oracom.Parameters.Clear();`
after `executenonquery();`

Comment: Solved my issue